# useContext API State doesn't pass another component

Tags: reactjs, express, components, mern

I am trying to pass a state to another component but it doesn't work. Here is my app.js file. Can someone please advise me on what's wrong here?

I'm creating the userContext in App.js and I want to use it in other files. In this code, I'm trying to use the userContext in the Navbar component.

```
function App() {
      const [login, setLogin] = useState(0);
      return (
        <userContext.Provider value={[setLogin, login]}>
          <BrowserRouter>
              <Navbar />
              <Routes>
                  {...routes}
              </Routes>
          </BrowserRouter>
        </userContext.Provider>
      );
}
    
export default App;

const Navbar = () => {
      const [login, setLogin] = useContext(userContext);
        
      const logout = () => {
        setLogin(0);
      };

    if (login) {
        return <button onClick={() => setLogin(0}>Logout</button>
    }

    return <button onClick={() => setLogin(1}>Login</button>
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the context value in the App.js as:

```js
<userContext.Provider value={[setLogin, login]}>
```

And when you are using the context value you are destructuring it in different order:

```js
const [login, setLogin] = useContext(userContext);
```

Which means that your setLogin function and login state get mixed up. Change the oder of the elements in the provider to:

```js
<userContext.Provider value={[login, setLogin]}>
```